# Unable to use patchValue method in Angular Forms

Tags: angular, forms

Data did not appear in an edit page. I got the data from API, and that data I'm able to get into a service.ts file also, but I'm not able to display it on the edit page.

> Edit.customer.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CustomerService } from './customer.service';
import { Customer } from '../models/customer.model';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators, FormControl } from "@angular/forms";
import { Router } from "@angular/router";
import { first } from "rxjs/operators";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-edit-customer',
  templateUrl: './edit-customer.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./edit-customer.component.css']
})
export class EditCustomerComponent implements OnInit {

  customer: Customer;
  editForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder, private router: Router, private _customerService: CustomerService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    let id = localStorage.getItem("editCustomerId");
    if (!id) {
      alert("Invalid Action")
      this.router.navigate(['list']);
      return;
    }
    this.editForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      customerId: [],
      name: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
      email: ['', Validators.required],
      primaryPhone: ['', Validators.required],
      alternatePhone: [''],
      address1: ['', Validators.required],
      address2: ['', Validators.required],
      address3: [''],
      city: ['', Validators.required],
      state: ['', Validators.required],
      country: ['', Validators.required],
      zip: ['', Validators.required],
    });    
    this._customerService.getCustomerById(+id).subscribe(data => {
      this.editForm.patchValue(data);
      console.log(data);
    });
  }
  onSubmit() {
    this._customerService.updateCustomer(this.editForm.value)
      .pipe(first())
      .subscribe(
        data => {
          this.router.navigate(['list']);
        },
        error => {
          alert(error);
        });
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your HTML Code?

Comment: HTML CODE:

<form [formGroup]="editForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="name">Customer Name:</label>
          <input type="text" formControlName="name" placeholder="Customer Name" name="name" class="form-control" />      
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="email">Email:</label>
          <input type="email" formControlName="email" placeholder="Email" name="email" class="form-control" id="email" />
        </div>
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Update</button>
      </form>

Comment: SERVICE.TS 
updateCustomer(customer: Customer) {
    return this.http.put(this._global.baseUrl + '/Customer/UpdateCustomer/' + customer.customerId, customer, {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      })
    });
  }

Comment: Have posted an answer, have a look at":

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to define the key for the [`PatchValue`](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup#patchvalue) method:

For ex.

```
this.yourform.patchValue({key : "value" });
```

You can do this dynamically also, with

```
this.yourform.patchValue({[key] : [value]});
```

In your case:

```
// This is your data from API
var data = {
  name: "Prashant",
  email: "prashantpimpale93@gmail.com"
}

// use the patch value with dynamic keys
Object.keys(data).forEach(key => {
  this.editForm.patchValue({ [key]: data[key] });
})
```

With data from API Service:

```
this._customerService.getCustomerById(id).subscribe(value => {
  if (value) {
     this.data = value;
  }
});

// Then use patchValue
Object.keys(this.data).forEach(key => {
   this.editForm.patchValue({ [key]: this.data[key] });
})
```

[StackBlitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jarrus)

**EDIT:**

As I checked your code, the API is returning List of object [Which shouldn't],

Just replace your API with this:

```
this.userService.getCustomerById(id).subscribe(value => {
  if (value) {
    // the value is an array just get the first item from list
    this.data = value[0];
    Object.keys(this.data).forEach(Key => {
    this.editForm.patchValue({ [Key]: this.data[Key] })
    })
  }
})
```

I have tested in my local environment!

Comment: Hi, @prashat

could you please let me know how to fetch the data from API. In your example, there is no code to get the data from API. 
At present I'm using this method to get the data. But how to modify it based on your answer.
this._customerService.getCustomerById(+id).subscribe(data => {
      this.editForm.patchValue(data);
      console.log(data);
    });

Comment: In that console.log(data); I'm able to get the customer details.

Comment: @murthy how the `data` looks like?

Comment: @murthy Have edited an  answer as per your requirement

Comment: HI, @prashant, the code not working for me.

**EditCustomerComponent_Host.ngfactory.js? [sm]:1 ERROR TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
    at Function.keys (<anonymous>)
    at EditCustomerComponent.push../src/app/customer/edit-customer.component.ts.EditCustomerComponent.ngOnInit (edit-customer.component.ts:48)
    at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.js:9243)
    at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.js:10507)
    at checkAndUpdateNode (core.js:10469)
    at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.js:11102)
    at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.js:11062)**

Comment: **at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (EditCustomerComponent_Host.ngfactory.js? [sm]:1)
    at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:11054)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:10451)**

Comment: @murthy How this line looks like -> *edit-customer.component.ts:48*

Comment: You want to call an api with formData?

Comment: I want to do form edit operation. At present i get the data based on customerId but unable to display that data in edit.component.html page. In your example i get the data up to this.data = value; without any errors. But i get those errors in **patchvalue**. 
please refer the my html code once. may be i did the mistake in that place also.

Comment: @murthy Ok, add the code here and data that you are getting!

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/16Ety9pTub8n6jGacIKgjMdK_2i3jbrjS/view?usp=sharing
Try to access that file once.

Comment: @murthy it would be better if you provide a base URL to hit an api

Comment: @murthy Can you post the response that you are getting in `data`?

Comment: BaseURL to hit an API will do a work, If possible otherwise, quite complicated

Comment: Watch this video once. you get the some clarity about current issue.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1shjYWSMuDazcG72-jJ9NW-x_a_vuvVbV/view

Comment: Just saw your video! nothing wrong with implementation

Comment: Thank you Prashant, Now I'm able to get the data and display it in edit.html page.
But update operation is not working to me.

Comment: Post another question with the latest error and data

Comment: As this question quite long and will be difficult to understand!